# How to group by in mongodb and keep all fields?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections: products and categories:

products:

```
{
  _id:1
  name:"product1"
  category: 1
  price:2399
},
{
  _id:2
  name:"product2"
  category: 2
  price:566
}
```

categories:

```
{
  _id:1
  name:"category1"
},
{
  _id:2
  name:"category2"
}
```

I've tried to use $group and $push but with no luck,
How can i group the products by their categories and achieve this query result:

```
categories: [
{
  _id:1
  name:"category1"
  products: [{
    _id:1
    name:"product1"
    category: 1
    price:2399
  }]
},
{
  _id:2
  name:"category2"
  products: [{
    _id:1
    name:"product2"
    category: 2
    price:566
  }]
}]
```

Comment: I did a lookup on field "category" already, but it just populates the category, i want to return my products grouped by their categories

Comment: Yaa, could you show what have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join then perform query on mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035222/how-to-join-then-perform-query-on-mongoose)

Comment: @TwoHorses : Why don't you do this operation on `categories collection` ?